# Is Worf still an ambassador?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, worf

In the final episodes of DS9, Martok became Chancellor of the Klingon High Council and Worf was named Federation Ambassador to the Klingon homeworld. However, in Nemesis, Worf is back in uniform and seamlessly resumes his position as tactical officer on board the Enterprise.

It's no surprise that he was present at the beginning of the movie as he was friends with both Riker and Troi so he would have good reason to attend their wedding.

I don't recall any instance of a Federation ambassador also being an active Starfleet officer. That said, I was surprised that Worf still had his commission and, apparently, being assigned to the Enterprise again in Nemesis after having been an ambassador for three or four years.

Also, following the events of the DS9 episode Change of Heart, when Worf was told in no uncertain terms that he was unlikely to get his own command, it would make more sense for him to pursue a career in diplomacy where there would be more opportunity for advancement.

So, is there any explanation for Worf being back in uniform, with his commission intact and no mention of him being or having been an ambassador in Nemesis?

I'm especially curious because, following the events of Nemesis with regards to the command staff of the Enterprise, there has been some speculation that Worf became Picard's new first officer (the deleted scene not withstanding) which seems odd because it seems like he would be going backwards in his career to take a terminal position.

Comment: There is no reason he would need to resign.

Comment: It was never said that he had to resign but other Starfleet officers turned diplomats all appear to have done so prior to changing careers (Spock and Archer for example) which at least implies that it's a requirement rather than a personal decision on their part.

Comment: both of those were fairly old when that happened. Memory alpha shows that there is a mandatory retirement age.

Comment: Very funny to consider Worf never getting a command when Dorn was trying to make a Captain Worf show

Comment: In [Star Trek Online Worf](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Worf) is a *Klingon* Ambassador.  While STO isn't canon, it's more coherent than most of the non-canon material and features many of the same actors.

Comment: @eliyahu-g It was only unlikely that Worf would never get his own command. In Sisko's own words: "*...and to be completely honest, you probably won't be offered a command on your own after this.*" There is a lot of ambiguity in there: is that Sisko's opinion or has the admiralty board told Sisko that outside of special circumstance or a life-time of exceptional service it won't happen? Also, Worf could probably get his own command in the Klingon fleet fairly easily, as a member of the house of Martoq, as a friend of the Chancellor or as a friend of the Emperor.

Comment: Unfortunately, *First Contact*, *Insurrection*, and *Nemesis* all feature contrived ways of getting Worf back on the Enterprise.  It was fine to do it once in *First Contact*.  In *Insurrection*, they couldn't even take it seriously in the film.  When Worf is about to explain why he was "passing through", Picard basically cuts him off and says he doesn't care.  Why would Worf be passing through anywhere without the Defiant at the height of the Dominion War?

Comment: @Praxis I've often wondered who had a greater need for attention and or money- Jonathan Frakes or Michael Dorn. Dorn, for his part, became a cast member on DS9 after TNG went off the air and then threw continuity out the nearest airlock when a new TNG era movie came about so he could be on it too. Frakes, on the other hand, did guest spots as a character he played on TNG on EVERY subsequent Star Trek series-including, somehow, Enterprise.

Comment: @geewhiz : Indeed.  Frakes' guest spot as Riker in the final episode of *Enterprise* is both laughable and cringe-worthy, playing a version of himself set in the final season of *TNG* (1994) but having aged 11 years.  No amount of make-up or tightening of his tunic makes him look the part.  Even if he could have pulled it off, it was a silly way to end *Enterprise*.  No matter how many times I watch that episode, the connection Riker is looking for regarding Tucker and the events in *Pegasus* are highly tenuous and random.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**No he's not.** It's clear from [the original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html) that he quit his job and returned to Starfleet.

> **BEVERLY :** *I'm so glad you made it back to the Enterprise before I left.*
>
> **WORF :** *I was not suited for the life of a... diplomat.*
>
> **BEVERLY :** (wry) *Who'd have guessed?*

These lines were cut from the film, leading to the confusion over his status.

---

The [novelisation](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis_%28novel%29) fleshes out the scene without adding much extra info, unfortunately:

> *"I'm so glad you made it back to the Enterprise before I left," she
>   called over the din of the music. To her, dance came naturally; her
>   bones were long and fine, her muscles limber and blessed with that
>   mystery known as a sense of rhythm. She could scarcely have resisted
>   dragging the Klingon onto the floor even if he'd been unconscious.*
>
> *Worf's pained expression eased slightly; it was the closest he would
>   come to acknowledging mutual affection. To those unfamiliar with
>   Klingons, he would have seemed ferocious, with the great jutting
>   browbone above narrowed eyes and jagged teeth; to Beverly he looked
>   precious. **"I was not suited for the life of a...diplomat."***

Comment: Thanks! That seems like an important line to cut but it does answer my question.

Comment: @user3053242 - They also trimmed out Wesley for no good reason.

Comment: @Richard - Wesley could use a good trim

Comment: Wes was supposed to be off exploring other planes of existence with the Traveler. I've seen the scene they cut out with him in it. He was in the correct uniform sitting at the table with the crew. That raised more questions than Worf being in uniform. I would have cut that scene just because most of the viewing audience would have immediately responded with "When did he...? Isn't he supposed to be..? Huh?"

Comment: @user3053242 - Nah, it would have just taken a single throwaway line like "glad to see you're back with us mere mortals, Wesley". "You know I wouldn't miss this" and then he could toast them and be done with it.

Comment: Yep, I think we can all agree there's plenty of other scenes ripe for cutting in that particular film...

Comment: It's scenes like that the writers and the directors and the producer goes......"why did we add that?! CUT IT!" in hindsight. lol

Comment: in the case of Nemesis @MissouriSpartan - the director had no ability to even understand why this would be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

While it may be customary for a Starfleet officer to resign prior to accepting a diplomatic role, that may be dependent on the assignment.  The Klingons would probably hold a military officer in higher regard than a civilian, so it would have made sense for Worf to not resign.

Comment: So is Worf still an ambassador? I assume you mean yes but would help to make it explicit.